# Is there anything wrong with my function implementation?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops

I need to write a function that will take the user input and do the following formula attached, however I keep getting the wrong output and cant seem what is the logical error in my code

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int functX(int x) {
  int fx = 1;

  for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
    fx *= (x + i);
  }

  return fx;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  cout << " Enter the value you want to sum" << endl;
  cin >> n;

  cout << functX(n) << endl;

  system("Pause");
  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Side note: this task could be easier if you solved the equation on paper, but I don't know what is the actual purpose of the task you have.

Comment: not sure what do you mean with that the purpose of it is learning to create a function

Comment: Think about what that series is showing you... It take `x` and add `2 * x`, then add `3 * x`, etc. Now what is your loop doing? Are you sure it's doing the same thing? You sure you haven't switched the `*` and `+` in your code?

Comment: While we&#39;re at it, consider ditching the loop and using the obvious mathematical expansion `n*(n+1)/2` for n==15 to calculate it in constant time: `int functX(int x) { return 120*x; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `f` seems to be implemented incorrectly; you seem to have exchanged additiond and multiplication. A correct implementation could look as follows.

```
int functX(int x)
{
    int fx = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
    {
        fx += (i * x);
    }
    return fx;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
fx *= (x + i);
```

write

```
fx += (x * i);
```

since you want to add the products and not multiply the sums.

Comment: OP also needs to initialise `fx` to 0, not 1.